# Coldfusion ReReplace finding numbers and replacing with a new number

Tags: coldfusion

Sorry but I am very new to Coldfusion and I need some help please.

I have a string that contains a recipe method. "Heat your oven to 200c and then blah blah until internal temperature measures 60c"

1. I need to replace the numeric values in the string with a dynamically calculated value and then it will look like this: "Heat your oven to 200c (392f) and then blah blah until internal temperature measures 60c (140f)".

These numeric values can appear anywhere and multiple times in the string.
The calculation to convert from C to F is C * 9/5 + 32.

So I need to ReReplace all numbers in the string with a new value calculated dynamically.

I hope this is clear.

Comment: The replaceWithCallback() UDF on CFLib should help you do what you need: http://www.cflib.org/udf/replaceWithCallback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my method of doing it.

```
<cfscript>
  sString = "Heat your oven to 200c and then cook till the temp internally is 60c";

  aFind = ReMatchNoCase("\d+c",sString);

  x = 0;
  while(x < arrayLen(aFind)){
    x++;
    nCalc = RematchNoCase("\d+",aFind[x])[1];


    nCalc = nCalc*9/5+32;
    sString = ReReplaceNoCase(sString,aFind[x],'#aFind[x]# (#ncalc#F)');
  }

  writeOutput(sString); 
</cfscript>
```

Adams linked UDF might be better, but I guess this code example, serves as a look into how you might accomplish it without a 3rd party.

Comment: Do you need to use `reReplaceNoCase()` there? It's just a straight string replacement isn't it? Also, *at a bare minimum* this should be wrapped in a function. I'd also consider putting the temperature conversion in its own function too, to make it cleaner code. It *also* seems a bit odd to use a `while()` loop to loop over an array. Why would you not use a `for-in` loop?

Comment: @AdamCameron is right in that this should be it's own function, and also the temp conversion should be extrapolated out to it's own function.  The while loop is just because I don't use `for-in` for arrays at work (because I can't), so just going with how I would do it at work.

Comment: @Jarede - For older versions that do not support `for-in`, I prefer `from/to` loops. They are a little shorter/cleaner, since the index declaration and increment/decrement is done in one line.